# Issue with Flutter Auto-Route

Tags: flutter, dart

Earlier i was using the auto_route and it works fine but after version upgrade and i can't use the same code.

Flutter Version - 3.7.10
Auto_Route Version - 6.0.5

It seems like something has changed with the new release in auto_route.

Earlier these codes were working but now it seems something has changed in auto_route.

**Router.dart**

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: [
    // initial route is named "/"
    MaterialRoute(page: AnimatedSplashScreen, initial: true),
    MaterialRoute(page: ChangeProfilePic),
  ],
)
class $Router {}
```

If Anyone has implemented recently the auto_route in the flutter app then please share the code for router.dart and how you are calling the routes.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a [breaking change](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#migrating-to-v6)

Comment: This is a tutorial with auto_route v2: [flutter_navigation_tutorial](https://github.com/gbaccetta/flutter_navigation_tutorial); exactly the same tutorial, upgraded to auto_route v6: [flutter_navigation_tutorial](https://github.com/Tyrn/flutter_navigation_tutorial). The last commit/tag (`auto_route v6`) shows off all the changes.